# Maximum number of iterations for LibSVM svmtrain function

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I use the [LibSVM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) package to train a support vector machine (SVM) in MATLAB. Calling the training function as shown below works fine:

```
model = svmtrain(train_label, train_set, '-s 0 -t 2');
```

Now, I want to set the maximum number of iterations `MaxIter` to 500.
I tried the following:

```
model = svmtrain(train_label, train_set, '-s 0 -t 2', MaxIter, 500);
```

but that returns an error:

> Undefined function or variable `'MaxIter'`.

How can I specify the maximum number of iterations for the LibSVM `svmtrain`  function?

Comment: you need the option quote arround MaxIter, i.e: `'MaxIter'`

Comment: For the future "doesnt work" its **not** a good explanation. Of course it doesnt work, else you wouldn't be asking! You need to describe in detail the error you get. Something like "undefined MaxIter"

Comment: AFAIK the LibSVM `svmtrain` doesn't have an option to set the maximum number of iterations. I'd be surprised if `'MaxIter'` works.

Comment: Are you talking about [`libsvm`](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) package? If yes, then it doesn't have `MaxIter`. It has termination criteria to reduce the number of iterations SVM will train for (don't change it unless you know what and why you are doing it). You don't have a control on maximum iterations.

Comment: it doesn't work even when  l make 'MaxIter' . here is the returned error

Comment: Usage: model = svmtrain(training_label_vector, training_instance_matrix, 'libsvm_options');
libsvm_options:
-s svm_type : set type of SVM (default 0)
 0 -- C-SVC  (multi-class classification)
 1 -- nu-SVC  (multi-class classification)
 2 -- one-class SVM
 3 -- epsilon-SVR (regression)
 4 -- nu-SVR  (regression)

Comment: -t kernel_type : set type of kernel function (default 2)
 0 -- linear: u'*v
 1 -- polynomial: (gamma*u'*v + coef0)^degree
 2 -- radial basis function: exp(-gamma*|u-v|^2)
 3 -- sigmoid: tanh(gamma*u'*v + coef0)
 4 -- precomputed kernel (kernel values in training_instance_matrix)
-d degree : set degree in kernel function (default 3)
-g gamma : set gamma in kernel function (default 1/num_features)
-r coef0 : set coef0 in kernel function (default 0)
-c cost : set the parameter C of C-SVC, epsilon-SVR, and nu-SVR (default 1)

Comment: -n nu : set the parameter nu of nu-SVC, one-class SVM, and nu-SVR (default 0.5)
-p epsilon : set the epsilon in loss function of epsilon-SVR (default 0.1)
-m cachesize : set cache memory size in MB (default 100)
-e epsilon : set tolerance of termination criterion (default 0.001)
-h shrinking : whether to use the shrinking heuristics, 0 or 1 (default 1)
-b probability_estimates : whether to train a SVC or SVR model for probability estimates, 0 or 1 (default 0)
-wi weight : set the parameter C of class i to weight*C, for C-SVC (default 1)

Comment: -v n : n-fold cross validation mode
-q : quiet mode (no outputs)
model file should be a struct array
0.004981
0.004231

Comment: Yes l'm using libsvm package. So we can't control the number of iteration of our gradient descent on svm ? Parag S. Chandakkar